# How to filter yesterday in the array of dates

Tags: javascript, dayjs

How to filter yesterday in the array of dates.  Right now, the output of the `filter` is the todays date. It should output the `2023-25-01`

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_isYesterday);

const arrOfDates = [ 1674670772417, 1674604800000, 1674518400000 ]
console.log( dayjs( arrOfDates[ 0 ] ).format( 'YYYY-DD-MM' ) ) // Should output 2023-26-01
console.log( dayjs( arrOfDates[ 1 ] ).format( 'YYYY-DD-MM' ) ) // Should output 2023-25-01
console.log( dayjs( arrOfDates[ 2 ] ).format( 'YYYY-DD-MM' ) ) // Should output 2023-24-01

arrOfDates.filter( date => {
    if ( dayjs( date ).add( -1, 'day' ).isYesterday() ) {
    console.log(dayjs(date).format('YYYY-DD-MM'), 'Result') // outputs 2023-26-01 which is incorrect. It should only output 2023-25-01
    }
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/plugin/isYesterday.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so use filter the way it is supposed to work? return a boolean. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `dayjs( date ).add( -1, 'day' )` while filtering. this updates the date value before checking `isYesterday`

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_isYesterday);

const arrOfDates = [ 1674670772417, 1674604800000, 1674518400000 ]
//const arrOfDates = [ dayjs().add(-1, 'day'), dayjs(), dayjs().add(1, 'day') ]
console.log( dayjs( arrOfDates[ 0 ] ).format( 'YYYY-DD-MM' ) ) // Should output 2023-26-01
console.log( dayjs( arrOfDates[ 1 ] ).format( 'YYYY-DD-MM' ) ) // Should output 2023-25-01
console.log( dayjs( arrOfDates[ 2 ] ).format( 'YYYY-DD-MM' ) ) // Should output 2023-24-01

arrOfDates.filter( date => {
if ( dayjs( date ).isYesterday() ) {
console.log(dayjs(date).format('YYYY-DD-MM'), 'Result') // outputs 2023-26-01 which is incorrect. It should only output 2023-25-01
return true;
}
return false;
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/plugin/isYesterday.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without external libs you can use  the date function and methods.

```js
const arrOfDates = [ 1674670772417, 1674604800000, 1674518400000 ];
const yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1)).toISOString().substring(0, 10);

arrOfDates.forEach( date => {
  const _ = new Date(date).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  if (_ === yesterday) {
    res = _
  }
});
console.log( res );
```